# add a list of custom values as an additional column to the end of an SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have performed a query like this

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', "submitted_at" AS "submitted_at", count(distinct "user_id") AS "count"
FROM table
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', "submitted_at")
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', "submitted_at") ASC
```

which returns a table like this (date simplified)

```
Date         count 
may 2020       7
june 2020      9
july 2020     20
aug 2020      35
sep 2020      89
oct 2020     104
```

I want to add a 3rd column with custom values like below

```
Date         count   value 
may 2020       7       9
june 2020      9      17
july 2020     20      38
aug 2020      35      94
sep 2020      89      41
oct 2020     104      78
```

how do I change my query such that I can add the additional column and get the above table with manually entered values? I've tried the below with no luck. The data is sat on different databases so I can't join the data directly. I'd also need to perform this query without creating any new tables within the database as am going to have to perform a similar query over a wide variety of cases and can't create tables each time I need to do this kind of thing. This is in a postgres database if that's relevant.

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', "submitted_at" AS "submitted_at", count(distinct "user_id") AS "count", (9,17,38,94,41,78) as "value"
FROM table
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', "submitted_at")
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', "submitted_at") ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `join` with `values`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', "submitted_at") AS "submitted_at", 
       count(distinct "user_id") AS "count", 
       v.val as "value"
FROM table t LEFT JOIN
     (VALUES ('2020-05-01', 9),
             ('2020-06-01', 17),
             . . .
     ) v(mon, val)
     ON date_trunc('month', "submitted_at") = v.mon
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', "submitted_at"), v.val
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', "submitted_at") ASC;
```

I am making what seems like a reasonable assumption that you want the values aligned by month.

Comment: amazing, that worked, I had to remove the t in your from clause and add v.val to group by, but otherwise good. Thanks!